# __toString return name from another entity

Tags: symfony

Let say I have 2 tables in my database : lesson and group. Group can have 1 lesson per year.

Then I will have 2 entities, lesson entity :

```
<?php
namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Lesson
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    */
    private $id;


    /**
    * @var string
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * Set id
    *
    * @param integer $id
    * @return DftGrupMapel
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

and group entity :

```
<?php
namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Group
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    */     
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstLesson
     */
    private $idLesson;

    /**
    * @var integer
    */
    private $year;

    /**
    * Set id
    *
    * @param integer $id
    * @return DftGrup
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set idLesson
     *
     * @param \Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstLesson $idLesson
     * @return DftGrup
     */
    public function setIdLesson(\Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstLesson $idLesson = null)
    {
        $this->idLesson = $idLesson;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idGrup
     *
     * @return \Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstGrup 
     */
    public function getIdLesson()
    {
        return $this->idLesson;
    }

    /**
    * Set year
    *
    * @param integer $year
    * @return DftGrup
    */
    public function setYear($year)
    {
        $this->year = $year;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get year
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getYear()
    {
        return $this->year;
    }
```

The problem is, in **group** entity I don't have available string to show for `__toString()`. I fell not good for making new `name` field in **group** entity and save **lesson** `name` there.

`lesson.id` and `group.idLesson` is foreign key.

How I can get `name` field in **lesson** entity to show in `__toString()` **group** without create new field?

Comment: Use camel_case for Classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ORM. Your `Group` class shouldn't really care about what it's associated `Lesson`'s *id* is... it should just have a reference to the `Lesson` object itself:

```
<?php
namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Group
{
    private $id;      // An integer
    private $lesson;  // A Lesson object
    private $year;    // An integer, probably
```

Once `$lesson` is a `Lesson` object, you can refer to it in your `Group::__toString()`:

```
private function __toString() {
    return $this->lesson->getName();
}
```

Here's the documentation on association mapping, which should be helpful in mapping the relationship between `Group` and `Lesson`:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: hmm, is there any way I can do that without make an object reference (arrayCollection) ?

Comment: After searching about this problem, seems best practice is using Collection. Thank you for answer. I'll pick this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function setIdLesson(\Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstLesson $idLesson = null)
  {
    $this->idLesson = $idLesson;
    return $this;
  }
```

Here,you don't need the return statement.

Comment: Well, this is not answer the question. I think there is no problem with or without return statement there.